# If a cursor is not defined at window creation, why does Windows load a default cursor only when the user hovers over the frame or titlebar?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Experimenting with attempts to create a Win32 window with minimal code I discovered a strange (perhaps undocumented) behavior. If the programmer omits defining a cursor in the WNDCLASSEX struct or defines the cursor as:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc
...
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
```

The window will be displayed but never activate unless the user hovers the mouse over a border or the title bar. I found out that Windows was constantly sending WM_SETCURSOR messages as well as the normal messages expected during application startup and window creation when over the client area. I never noticed this in the past until I created a window that was initially borderless. That window displayed a continuous "wait" cursor (spinning circle). This behaviour can be reproduced with the following code. Since I could not find any explanation on MSDN or other sites, I just wanted to put this out there for others to find. To see this, run this code and make sure the cursor is over the client area when the window is created.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    HINSTANCE hinstance(GetModuleHandleW(0));
    WNDCLASSEXW wc({ 0 });

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    //wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;// | CS_OWNDC; // unneeded
    wc.lpszClassName = L"classname";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hinstance;
    //wc.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1); // unneeded
    //wc.hIcon         = LoadIconW(0, IDI_APPLICATION); // unneeded
    //wc.hIconSm       = wc.hIcon; // unneeded
    //wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(hinstance, IDC_ARROW); // will not activate properly
    //wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(0, IDC_ARROW); // needed for proper activation


    if (!RegisterClassExW(&wc)) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE;

    HWND handle = CreateWindowExW(0, L"classname", L"Test Window"
                                     , style, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT
                                     , CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0
                                     , (HMENU)0, hinstance, 0);
    if (!handle)
        return -1;

    MSG msg;

    while (1) {
        while (PeekMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                return ((int)msg.wParam);
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do not customize `WM_SETCURSOR`, then it sets the cursor based on `hCursor` for the client area, and based on system defaults for non-client areas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I obsessively spent an entire day trying to figure out what was happening.  I could find nothing about it in the online documentation. But it does seem, once assigned, Windows continues to use the default cursor for the client area.

Comment: Once assigned, the cursor holds that value until reassigned. Windows is not "using the default cursor for the client area" so much as it is "not making any changes to the cursor when it is in the client area", so the previous value carries forward. [The behavior of WM_SETCURSOR is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor).